R ggplot's linewidth is thicker than specified when writing to pdf, but not in print
My problem cosists of two parts:

Very thin lines (or very small symbols) in ggplot look different in the plot viewer or a png (left) than when I save them to pdf (right):

    df = data.frame(Year = rep(seq(1, 100), 100),
                    Y = rep(rep(1:5, each = 100), 20),
                    N = rep(1:100, each = 100),
                    X = rnorm(n = 100*100))
      
    
    (p2 = ggplot() + theme_classic() +
        geom_line(data = df, linewidth = .01, alpha = 1,
                  aes(x = Year, y = X, color = Y, group = N)) +
        scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-2,2)))

ggsave("thick_line.png")
ggsave("thick_line.pdf")

 
No matter how thin I set the linewidth, the pdf will always look the same. The actual plot as other elements (e.g. plotting the mean) that are not visible like this. This issue has already been addressed here, but I am using ggsave() already, so the suggested solution does not work for me.
I can adapt the plot in other ways, such that the pdf (again right) look nice, in this example e.g. through alpha:
(p2 = ggplot() + theme_classic() +
    geom_line(data = df, linewidth = .01, alpha = .1,
              aes(x = Year, y = X, color = Y, group = N)) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-2,2)))

 
Now comes my other problem:

If I adapt the plot, such that the pdf looks nice, when printed it will look like the png (left), meaning the lines will not be visible at all. This is my thesis, so both the digital version and print version need to look nice.

It seems to me, that there is some minial linewidth the pdf is rendered, but in printing this is lost when converting to pixels. The problem persist in multiple pdf readers.
Possible back-up solutions are

Saving the plots as pngs, but this will never look as nice as pdfs in the rendered digital document
Having two versions of every plot, one for digital and one for print. Obviously not very practicable.

How can I export my ggplots as pdfs in a way that looks consistent in digital and print?

The exported pdf has no stroke width  at all. What you're seeing is the default width. You either need to edit the  pdf, or export to svg which will persever the stroke width and convert the svg to pdf.

It looks like pdf ignores the alpha, as well. When you remove these parameters the plots nearly match. (I think the pdf still looks a bit more crisp...which is really sad if you think about it).
